# how to send email in php from fetch or taken from a variable in a txt file

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

`

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "r");

$members = array();

var_dump($members);

$mail->addAddress ($members);

enter code here
```

//I would like to assigned  $members which has email address in file and assigned to  $mail->addAddress
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = sprintf("%s email.\n",$row['email']);**strong text**
$mail->addAddress ($row['email']);
```